# Uploading files with ajax $_POST empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload files from a form asynchronously, but I have a problem

I add the form files this way

```
function composeFormData(oldFormData,form){

    oldFormData.push({name:"doc_files",value:doc_filestore});
    oldFormData.push({name:"desc_files",value:filestore});

    $.ajax({
      url: "save.php",
      data: oldFormData,
      type: "POST", 
      dataType:"html",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      //processData: false
    }).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });

}
```

without `processData:` false ,the value of doc_files,and desc_files are a string instead of a file and with `processData: false`, $_POST is empty.
But before send  the request `formdata['desc_files']`
 and `formdata['doc_files']` are files arrays.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the context of your code, `oldFormData` appears to be an array. If so, that's your problem. It needs to be a `FormData` object. I'm closing this as a duplicate as there are literally hundreds of questions asking about how to upload files from jQuery to PHP, and the logic is identical.

Comment: oldFormData is formdata

Comment: In that case you will be getting an error as `push()` is not a method of a `FormData` object. Either way, the exact code you need is in the duplicate.